# Counting dictionary- list items python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following format

```
{'bye': ['yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'],
 'hello': ['red'],
 'hi': ['red', 'blue']}
```

What I'm trying to do is count all the values in this dictionary, no matter what the key is, no matter if the values have the same name, if its there count it.

So far i have

```
mynumber = 0
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
  mynumber +=1
return mynumber
```

This output only give me the total number of keys, what i want is the sum of all values, repeated or not. So in this instance mynumber should be 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a generator to `sum()`:

```
total = sum(len(item) for item in mydict.itervalues())
```